# How to return the max row based on one column in join query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query that returns a result set with some IDs from a few tables. If a get two or more rows with the same QuestionID I only want  the one with MAX(QuestionSessionID). How can I achieve this?

I have tried a bunch of different variations with subqueries but with no success. How to achieve this?

The query:

```
SELECT AQS.QuestionSessionID, AQS.QuestionID, AQS.AnswerTextMarkerID, AQS.Correct, QG.ID AS QuestionGroupID
FROM AnswerQuestionSession AQS
JOIN QuestionSession QS ON QS.UserID = 3 
JOIN Question Q ON AQS.QuestionID = Q.ID
JOIN QuestionGroup QG ON Q.QuestionGroupID = QG.ID
WHERE AQS.AnswerTextMarkerID IN (109,110,113,114,118,121,141,146,148,152,156,157,158,172,182,183,193,194,196,197,198,211,222,227,241,242,243,257,263,271,282,283,356,396,643,644,938,939,943,944,955,956,957,958,959,970,971,972,973,978,979,1110,1111,1112,1113,1114,1115,1116,1117,1118,1120,1121,1163,1164,1165,1166,1205,1240)
AND AQS.QuestionSessionID = QS.ID
ORDER BY AQS.QuestionID, AQS.QuestionSessionID DESC;
```

**Current result set:**

```
QuestionSessionID QuestionID AnswerTextMarkerID Correct QuestionGroupID
294441            112        121                1       25
22942             112        121                0       25
22942             126        141                1       39
131489            216        257                1       102
22942             222        263                1       106
22942             227        271                1       110
294435            760        955                1       5
294435            760        956                1       5
```

So, in the above example I only want one of the rows with QuestionID 112 (the one with MAX(QuestionSessionID) 294441), like this:

**Desired result set:**

```
QuestionSessionID QuestionID AnswerTextMarkerID Correct QuestionGroupID
294441            112        121                1       25
22942             126        141                1       39
131489            216        257                1       102
22942             222        263                1       106
22942             227        271                1       110
294435            760        955                1       5
294435            760        956                1       5
```

**UPDATE:**
Tried adding another join as suggested by a commenter, but didn't get it right. It seems to work only on rows with more than one of the same QuestionID:

```
SELECT AQS.QuestionSessionID, AQS.QuestionID, AQS.AnswerTextMarkerID, AQS.Correct, QG.ID AS QuestionGroupID, MaxId
FROM AnswerQuestionSession AQS
JOIN QuestionSession QS ON QS.UserID = 3 
JOIN Question Q ON AQS.QuestionID = Q.ID
JOIN QuestionGroup QG ON Q.QuestionGroupID = QG.ID
JOIN (SELECT QuestionID, MAX(QuestionSessionID) as MaxId
      FROM AnswerQuestionSession
      GROUP BY QuestionID) as mq ON mq.QuestionID = AQS.QuestionID
WHERE AQS.AnswerTextMarkerID IN (109,110,113,114,118,121,141,146,148,152,156,157,158,172,182,183,193,194,196,197,198,211,222,227,241,242,243,257,263,271,282,283,356,396,643,644,938,939,943,944,955,956,957,958,959,970,971,972,973,978,979,1110,1111,1112,1113,1114,1115,1116,1117,1118,1120,1121,1163,1164,1165,1166,1205,1240)
AND AQS.QuestionSessionID = QS.ID
/*AND AQS.QuestionSessionID = MaxId*/
ORDER BY AQS.QuestionID, AQS.QuestionSessionID DESC;
```

```
QuestionSessionID QuestionID AnswerTextMarkerID Correct QuestionGroupID MaxId
294441            112        121                1       25            294441
22942             112        121                0       25            294441
22942             126        141                1       39            293891
131489            216        257                1       102           294071
22942             222        263                1       106           294013
22942             227        271                1       110           294013
294435            760        958                1       5             294435
294435            760        959                1       5             294435
294435            760        955                1       5             294435
294435            760        956                1       5             294435
294435            760        957                1       5             294435
294435            771        970                1       241           294435
294435            771        971                1       241           294435
294435            771        972                1       241           294435
294435            776        978                1       245           294435
131489            962        1205               1       318           293592
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I got it to work as expected with a small modification based on help from a commenter:

**WORKING QUERY:**

```
SELECT AQS.QuestionSessionID, AQS.QuestionID, AQS.AnswerTextMarkerID, AQS.Correct, QG.ID AS QuestionGroupID
FROM AnswerQuestionSession AQS
JOIN QuestionSession QS ON  AQS.QuestionSessionID = QS.ID 
JOIN Question Q ON AQS.QuestionID = Q.ID
JOIN QuestionGroup QG ON Q.QuestionGroupID = QG.ID
JOIN (SELECT QuestionID, MAX(QuestionSessionID) as MaxId
      FROM AnswerQuestionSession AQS2
      JOIN QuestionSession QS2 ON AQS2.QuestionSessionID = QS2.ID
      WHERE QS2.UserID = 3
      GROUP BY QuestionID) as mq ON mq.QuestionID = AQS.QuestionID
WHERE AQS.AnswerTextMarkerID IN (109,110,113,114,118,121,141,146,148,152,156,157,158,172,182,183,193,194,196,197,198,211,222,227,241,242,243,257,263,271,282,283,356,396,643,644,938,939,943,944,955,956,957,958,959,970,971,972,973,978,979,1110,1111,1112,1113,1114,1115,1116,1117,1118,1120,1121,1163,1164,1165,1166,1205,1240)
AND QS.UserID = 3 
AND AQS.QuestionSessionID = MaxId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a JOIN against a subquery on the `AnswerQuestionSession` table

```
JOIN (SELECT QuestionID, MAX(QuestionSessionID as MaxId)
      FROM AnswerQuestionSession
      GROUP BY QuestionID) as mq ON mq. QuestionID = Aqs. QuestionID
```

and then use it in the `WHERE` clause

```
AND Aqs.QuestionSessionID = MaxId
```

---

This is based on the updated question, I changed the join on QuestionSession and also made sure MaxId was used in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT AQS.QuestionSessionID, AQS.QuestionID, AQS.AnswerTextMarkerID, AQS.Correct, QG.ID AS QuestionGroupID
FROM AnswerQuestionSession AQS
JOIN QuestionSession QS ON  AQS.QuestionSessionID = QS.ID
JOIN Question Q ON AQS.QuestionID = Q.ID
JOIN QuestionGroup QG ON Q.QuestionGroupID = QG.ID
JOIN (SELECT QuestionID, MAX(QuestionSessionID) as MaxId
      FROM AnswerQuestionSession
      GROUP BY QuestionID) as mq ON mq.QuestionID = AQS.QuestionID
WHERE AQS.AnswerTextMarkerID IN (109,110,113,114,118,121,141,146,148,152,156,157,158,172,182,183,193,194,196,197,198,211,222,227,241,242,243,257,263,271,282,283,356,396,643,644,938,939,943,944,955,956,957,958,959,970,971,972,973,978,979,1110,1111,1112,1113,1114,1115,1116,1117,1118,1120,1121,1163,1164,1165,1166,1205,1240)
AND QS.UserID = 3 
AND AQS.QuestionSessionID = MaxId
ORDER BY AQS.QuestionID, AQS.QuestionSessionID DESC;
```

Comment: @user9223839 thanks for your comment. Tried it but didn't work 100%, I updated the question with your suggestion and a new result set. Any ideas?

Comment: @user9223839 Updated the question with a working version (with a small modification, added another join to get the maxId) of the query based on this comment. Thank you!